# Application Insights query gives more results than the same Log Analytics Workspace query

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

as recommended by MS we migrated our Application Insights instance to Workspace based.

We face the issue that the same query in AI gives us different results than the one in the Workspace - the Workspace gives much less results - a complete time range block is missing.

Anyone has an idea what could be the reason?

Workspace:

[image: Workspace syntax]

AI:

[image: AI syntax]

I'm trying to get the logs using the new syntax, but it gives incomplete results.

Answer (score 0):

- I created application insights and connected to the workspace.

[image]

- Check below that I test the integration and it shows some logs.

[image]

- I created `Log Analytics Workspace` and migrated the data from Application Insights when it runs and shows Logs check below.

[image]

- The main difference of application insights and workspace is Application Insights it shows logs of every function. But, in Log Analytic workspace doesn't shows all functionalities.
- Log Analytics Workspace is a service that provides a centralized location for storing and analyzing log data from various sources, including Azure services and on-premises resources.
- You can modify the settings of logs by changing the time bound in log analytics or AI check below.

[image]

Comment: Logs that are migrated can take up to 24h to appear in LA. However my logs were written _after_ the migration already.

Comment: I just edited the answer check above.

Comment: Yes, you can do also in the query.